# Couldn't create a model by providing req.body

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've created a user model and exported it in controller,but during .create() function doesn't seem to work properly.Error displayed is TypeError: userModel.create is not a function, it should have created the table.

```
'use strict';


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const User = sequelize.define('user', {
        email: {
            type:  DataTypes.STRING,
            defaultValue:'',
            allowNull:false,
            validate: {
              notNull: true,
            }
          },
          name:{
              type:DataTypes.STRING,
              defaultValue:'',
              allowNull:true
          },
          city:{
              type:DataTypes.STRING,
              defaultValue:'',
              allowNull:true
          }
      },
      {
        freezeTableName: true,
      }
    );


    return User;
};


'use strict';


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const User = sequelize.define('user', {
        email: {
            type:  DataTypes.STRING,
            defaultValue:'',
            allowNull:false,
            validate: {
              notNull: true,
            }
          },
          name:{
              type:DataTypes.STRING,
              defaultValue:'',
              allowNull:true
          },
          city:{
              type:DataTypes.STRING,
              defaultValue:'',
              allowNull:true
          }
      },
      {
        freezeTableName: true,
      }
    );

    return User;
};
```

I've also tried     `const userModel = require('../../../models/user').User` but no luck
Below is usercontroller for  provided model

```
"use strict";

const userModel = require('../../../models/user')
```

saveUserProfile(req, res) {

```
    userModel.create(req.body).then(user => {
        console.log("User Data", user);
        res.send({ data: user })
    });
```

}

```
module.exports = new user();
```

Comment: You're exporting a function that expects to params. You're not exporting the `User` object. So you're require needs to pass invoke that function and pass `(sequelize, DataTypes)`

Comment: How Can i do that? That would be helpful

Comment: I've submitted an answer to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is exporting a function, not the `User` object. So you need to invoke the function with the dependencies within your controller in order to call `userModel.create`.

I assume your controller knows about `seqeulize` and `DataTypes`, otherwise you'll need to import them and pass them along, or `import` them directly within your `model`.

### Dependency Injection (somewhat)

Use the `require` statement below and inject `sequelize` and `DataTypes` from your controller.

```
const userModel = require('../../../models/user')(sequelize, DataTypes).User
```